# How does cartridge protection distinguish an original vs fake cartridge?

Tags: hardware

Based on what explained [here](https://www.inkntoneruk.co.uk/ink-cartridge-news/how-to-disable-hp-cartridge-protection/), genuine ink cartridges may come with cartridge protection embedded in their chip. Once an ink cartridge is installed, printer will mark it as protected.

What is embedded in the chip?

How can we make sure that it is original and not duplicated with a 3rd party?

Is this a safe and well-known offline security protocol? (it will be great if some one can point me to a reference about it)

Comment: Although the question is on hold, I can give you my short answer. It’s hard to know what type of chips are being used by the printer and cartridges but I bet it’s something like the Microchip’s ATSHA204A or ATTECC508. Google those chips and they can give you some info on how host - client authentication can be done with hardware.